# Matching the heights of child elements with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to write a function that will set the child elements of all rows with a particular class ("match-heights") to be the same height. So far it works ok, but bugs on resize, most often the actual tallest element will be some what shorter than the others after scaling the browser. Here is the code so far.

```js
function matchHeights(wrapper) {

  //get all the elements with the "wrapper" clas
  var match_height_elements = document.getElementsByClassName(wrapper); 
  //count the elements
  var match_height_count = match_height_elements.length; 

  //my tallest
  var my_tallest = 0; 

  //iterate through the "wrapper" elements
  for (var i = 0; i < match_height_count; i++) { 

    //get the children of the wrapper elements
    var children = match_height_elements[i].children; 

    //count the children
    var child_count = children.length; 

    //iterate through the child elements
    for (var j = 0; j < child_count; j++) { 

      //get the childs height
      var child_height = children[j].offsetHeight; 

      //if taller than my_tallest then
      if (child_height != null && child_height > my_tallest) { 

        my_tallest = child_height;
      }
    }

    //iterate through the child elements
    for (var k = 0; k < child_count; k++) { 

      //if height less than tallest
      if (children[k].offsetHeight < my_tallest) { 

        //set child height to tallest
        children[k].style.height = my_tallest + 'px'; 

      }
    }
  }
}

window.onload = matchHeights('match-heights');
window.addEventListener("resize", matchHeights);
```

```html
<div class="match-heights">
  <div>text</div>
  <div>much longer text Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin semper libero vel maximus tincidunt. Fusce lacus nisl, rhoncus vel nisi aliquam, egestas hendrerit tortor. Etiam eget luctus ex. Curabitur sed mi condimentum, vehicula ante non, scelerisque tellus. Duis risus magna, volutpat a suscipit et, aliquam volutpat lacus. Vivamus at magna ut tortor bibendum egestas vitae nec libero. Aliquam iaculis pretium volutpat. </div>
</div>
```

Solved! [nalply](https://stackoverflow.com/users/220060/nalply) below had it right. I added a slight delay to the resize event and that fixed it.

I changed

```
window.addEventListener("resize", matchHeights);
```

to

```
function matchHeightsDelay(){

    setTimeout(matchHeights('match-heights'), 10);

}

window.addEventListener("resize", matchHeightsDelay);
```

If anyone else has a way to improve this please let me know.

Comment: Perhaps rerun `matchHeights()` after a resize? Attention, this event can fire many times. You need to check whether the div has really changed and perhaps throttle the event rate, too.

Comment: You could also have the wrapper display flex.  Then toggle 'flex 1 1' on all of the child elements.  Having them display horizontally or vertically depending on your needs.